# How to append something in list which is in another python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose,
Content in `fileA.py`

```
# Content in fileA
import fileB
```

Content in `fileB.py`

```
# Content in fileB
fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Watermelon"]
```

So suppose I want to append something to the `fruits` list which is in the `fileB` from `fileA` how can I do that?

Comment: Updating `manage.tasks` will not modify `manage.py`.  So next time your application runs, `manage.tasks` will still be empty.  You need to use, for example `json` or `pickle` module, to store the changes on `manage.tasks` to a data file and load this data file on application start up.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should import the other file as a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

So in your `manage.py` where the list lives, you would have

```
SOME_LIST=[1, 2, 3]
```

And you should create an `__init__.py` file in that folder to ensure you can use it as a module.

Then in the file you want to use that list:

```
from manage import SOME_LIST

[your code]
```

Do note that if the manage.py file is in another directory, you need to specify the full path to where it is

```
from path.manage import SOME_LIST
```

You can use the list from that file as a constant, but modifying it permanently is another matter. If you want to read and write data, you would need to use some sort of file instead of a Python module. Maybe a JSON or a YAML. If the list is simple, maybe even a txt file where each line is one element of the list.

Comment: I have tried the ```manage.py```  is still empty